# Python - Compare similar values in two columns from two different csv

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files with the same row names:

```
Name, Lastname.
```

However, file2.csv has an extra column named

```
Attention
```

Each file has a different list of name and lastname (not in order). I'm trying to find a way to find to print the attention column, if the name and lastname are in both files.

This is what I have so far:

```
    with open('result.csv') as r:
        set1 = set(x[0] for x in csv.reader(r))

    with open('result2.csv') as r:
        set2 = set(x[0] for x in csv.reader(r))

    for x, y in zip(set1, set2):
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            print("Matched")
```

How can I read the first and second column for each file?

Thank you

edit: being more clear

Comment: How about using `x[1]`?

Comment: @Neo My bad, meant to say compare first and second column of each file.

Comment: It's not clear what is the comparison you want to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a set of tuples for the lookup table which will contain the values from your first two columns, e.g.:

```
with open("result.csv", "r") as f:
    result = {(x[0], x[1]) for x in csv.reader(f)}
```

And then just iterate over the second file, check if the tuple of the first two columns exists in the lookup table from the first file, and if yes - print the third column on each match, e.g.:

```
with open("result2.csv", "r") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if (row[0], row[1]) in result:
            print("Matched: {}".format(row[2]))  # print the third column
```